# xamarin.android.support.compat 28.0.0.1 is not compatible with netstandard2.0

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was wroking on a proyect in Xamarin.Forms (the proyect is saved in an server), everything was ok, but then I changed my laptop for a new one, so the problems started, first there were missing some dlls, I fixed them up but when I try to fix Android.Xamarin.Support.Compat it shows me an error about net.standart.

I tried downloading it from NuGet, and that didn't work.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxu3h.png)

Comment: That nuget should only be added to Xamarin.Android based projects, remove it from your Xamarin.iOS and NetStd2 projects.

Comment: Yes did that and it worked again, thanks!

Comment: @DaisukeDany If have solved , you can share it in answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deleted Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat reference and it worked again! Thanks @SushiHangover for the answer!